# How can I get only the name of Network adapter of a hyper-V host using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v

I am using the following command to get VMNetworkAdapter details:

```
Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS
```

This provides output in the following format:

Name                             IsManagementOs       VMName  SwitchName

I just want the switch name.
Do we have any option or flag?

edit: I found the new command to just get switch details

```
Get-VMSwitch
```

But this command also returns many fields, I want just the name of the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just need to select field

```
Get-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS|Select -ExpandProperty SwitchName
```